# Even though I added the Arc Hydro Tools to my toolboxes I cannot open and access the Arc Hydro Tools

Tags: arc-hydro

Even though I added the Arc Hydro Tools to my toolboxes I cannot open and access the Arc Hydro Tools.

[[image: As you can see below there is no expand button to access the Arc Hydro Tools 1]]

Comment: do you have Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst license, and is it enabled under Extensions?